# Can I make proprietary software with Julia?

Tags: gpl

[Julia](http://julialang.org/), a high-level, high-performance dynamic programming language for numerical computing that has some dependencies. One of them is GMP, an external library that has a GPL2+ license. In that case, can I make proprietary software with Julia?

Comment: Can you tell us what JULIA is and how it is used in making the proprietary software?

Comment: Julia is a high-level, high-performance dynamic programming language for numerical computing. https://julialang.org

Comment: Actually this is solved on Julia web page as you advised before. Here is the link:

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/what-is-it-for-gmp-external-library-used-by-julia/7893

We can delete the post here if it is not appropriate to repeat.

Comment: Is your software going to be a derivative work of Julia, or an independent work? If you make your own .jl files, that is most likely an independent work. If you combine Julia into your own product and sell that, that may be a derivative work and you'll need to adhere to Julia's and third party libs' licenses.

Comment: It will be a derivative work. But JULIA uses dynamic linking.

Comment: See this page for the license overview of third party components used by the Julia standard library: [LICENSE.md](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/LICENSE.md). There are some other LGPL and GPL components besides GMP, so if you distribute the whole standard library with your product, you'll probably need to adhere to their licenses too.

Comment: You are right. I need to investigate all of them.

Comment: @Brandin please make these comments an answer ;)

Answer (score 5):

It is possile if you add "USE_GPL_LIBS = 0" to the make.user file. By this way it will not include GPL dependent libraries during compilation. For more detailed discussion refer to the [link](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/is-julia-suitable-for-the-development-of-proprietary-derived-softwares/7912/22).